# re-set netbeans text anti-aliasing

Tags: windows, netbeans, fonts

I am using Netbeans for PHP development. Up until now I've been using Consolas font in the editor. I played around with different fonts the other day and I seemed to have lost the anti-aliasing in the editor. Whatever font I choose now it appears jagged - even Consolas.

I'm sure a setting must have got over-ridden somewhere.

I've tried tried resetting the Windows TrueType settings (other apps are fine) to no avail...

Searching the web seems to suggest that there are buried settings in Netbeans to turn anti-aliasing on or off. however the articles I've come across don't seem to match my version.

Windows 7, Netbeans IDE 7.2

very much appreciate help with this...

Comment: sorry, font name is Consolas...

Answer (score 4):

The version shouldn't matter. But since many people report that the default anti-aliasing behaviour can change with different (even newer Java or Netbeans versions), you should try the anti-aliasing setting that works best for you: All possible options are explained in the official [Netbeans Font Rendering FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering).

Those options can be set in `netbeans.conf` file (on Windows 7 this would be typically found in `C:\Program Files\Netbeans 7.2\etc`) or you can set a default font-rendering behaviour system-wide for **all** Java swing based applications by adjusting (setting, respectively) your `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable.

For me

`-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd`

worked like a charm on Windows 7, while

`-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on`

seemed to work better on Manjaro Linux (XFCE) for me.

Comment: thanks for a very detailed answer, especially as the question was asked 2.5 years ago :-) things moved on and at some point I had to re-install windows, which I guess solved the issue although I can't remember exactly how the issue was resolved...

Comment: Sure - but since i just ran into the same visual ugliness on a fresh installed win 7 system with Netbeans 8.02 i thought i'd share what worked for me.

Comment: great, and thanks for doing so... I'm not sure if this solution was the exact solution for the issue I had, so I'm not sure if I should should mark your answer as the correct one... I'm sure others will find it helpful in the future...